# Will I be able to easily port Qt applications?

Tags: c++, qt, testing, ide

If I create a Qt binary, then the user that starts it will not need to have Qt installed on their computer right? That is, it's like a native support of MFC - it starts everywhere (on Windows, if it was built as exe)? I know libraries should be static/included and so, but I am asking only about Qt compatibility.

Also, if I create a Qt project on Windows, do I need some extra work to use this project on Linux, given the version of Qt is the same? What about Mac?

Answer (score 3):

The Qt libraries will have to be installed on the target machine, unless you statically link the Qt libraries in your executable. (I do **not** recommend this, the resulting binaries will be huge.)

Depending on the licence you use Qt with, you could also ship the required Qt DLLs with your application.

As for portability, it's very good with Qt. It should compile and run fine as-is on Mac and Linux. (Possible problems are with file paths and such, but there are ways to make that work reliably and portably if you always use the Qt APIs.)

Comment: great,
About how huge? I just noticed yesterday that skype is over 25mb in one exe - on my windows...I guess anything less than 50mb should be fine in one binary...but i suspect that it will be way over 200-300mb? If that's the case I will rather continue with vs 6 and mfc...but qt seems to have so many good libraries + it's arguibly faster than .net - now that i am also considering .net for my project.

Comment: You can sum the size of the modules dll that you intend to use, 2.5Mb for QtCore and 10Mb for QtGui, to have an approximate size of the final executable size when compiled statically, and you can also UPX it to reduce that size.

Comment: @Jim: It's a coincidence that your VS6/MFC programs work without MFC install; it's a combination that was used quite a bit in the past so many computers do have those DLLs. But you can't rely on that. And as VC6 is 13 years old, nobody uses it anymore so those DLLs are becoming rare on new systems.

Comment: My program uses QtCore and QtGui, final executable + all DLL-s are ~5MB compressed.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Mat -- unless the application was specifically designed and written with portability in mind at all times, you will have to make many changes to get it to compile, to run, and to look good on Linux and Mac. Qt makes this process easier, but it is not entirely painless.

Comment: Well, I didn't say that out of the air. I've "ported" built Qt applications on Linux that worked out of the box on Windows. It's not hard _if you stick to Qt and **standard** C++_.

Answer (score 0):

The UI is pretty much bound to look ugly on other systems on the first run. Qt is, first and foremost, a unified UI creation system; meanwhile, in Windows, the menu is a part of the nonclient area of the window, on Mac, it's outside of the window (on screen top instead), and on Linux it's just one of the controls in the client area. Unify that. And don't get me started on the widget diversity on Linux.

So yeah, there will be a nonzero porting effort.

Comment: I can't agree with that. If you use the Qt widget set as it was intended (QMainWindow, the right classes for toolbars, etc.), the look-and-feel of the apps you get is quite consistent across platforms.

Comment: If you don't provide CONSIDERABLE size leeway for all controls, control text is bound to cut off here and there.

Comment: @Seva: You should anyway, or else you get the same cut-off in translated versions. Qt in fact deals rather nicely with that; I've seen much worse.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several separate issues to consider here:

1. Getting your Qt program to compile under various platforms
2. Deploying your Qt program on various platforms (so that "normal
   users" can install and run it without a lot of hassle)
3. Tweaking your Qt program's look and feel (so that it looks as
   "native" as possible under the various platforms it to run on)

(1) Is largely a matter of avoiding platform-specific APIs in your program.  If you stick to Qt and STL APIs you should be okay.  Or if you must use something platform-specific feature, you can do so via #ifdefs for each platform, or by providing separate .cpp files for each platform, but that is a hassle that's best avoided if possible.

(2) Requires slightly different steps for different platforms;  There is some documentation about it [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/deployment.html).

(3) May or may not be important to you (it depends on how much you care whether your program looks like a native application on each platform).  If it is important, then I don't think there is any way around manually trying your program out on each target platform and tweaking it until it looks "just right" for that platform.  It helps to design your GUI code to make as few hard-coded assumptions at possible (so that Qt's QStyle layer is free to the 'right thing' based on the current platform).